# how to get one ascx controls value from another ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Family.aspx page which contains a parent.ascx user control.

In parent.ascx contain two different user controls namely childA.ascx, childB.ascx and other five textboxes. Applying some logic I make child controls visible true or false.
In ChildA and childB user control contain five textbox controls equally.

In Parent.ascx.cs, I have SaveData method which saves entire data in DB. 
so the catch is how to get ChildA or ChildB textboxes values in parent.ascx.cs so I can call SaveData.

Answer (score 1):

If `ChildA` and `ChildB` are your custom user controls, you can expose values retrieved from `TextBox` controls as public properties (with some additional processing, if needed) and then read those properties in `Parent.ascx.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

You could store data in Session[] from the ChildA.ascx / ChildB.ascx. Than, when you call SaveData, you could manage the data as you want! Just an option, I really don't know the scenario of your web application.